# not desired output in web scraping in bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, jupyter, scrape

I am scraping an product information. But I scrape its price it doesn't give me proper output. There is no error but not the desired output.

And also it produce error while finding the category of a product.
Here is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas

url='https://shop.eziline.com/product/uncategorized/umrah-management-system/'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=bs(r.content,'html.parser')

name=soup.find(class_='product_title entry-title').text.strip()
print(name)
price=soup.find('span',class_='woocommerce-Price-amount amount').text.strip()
print(price)
detail=soup.find(class_='woo-product-details_short-description').text.strip()
print(detail)
category=soup.find('cats-link a').text.strip()
print(category)
```

Comment: It gives me the output R.s 0.00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are

1. picking up the first price rather than the target price. Instead, you can use the main content id as an anchor to the correct section to return the price from
2. You are trying to use css selector syntax in the last line without applying via the appropriate method and adding in the syntax for a class selector. You could also use `category=soup.find(class_='cats-link').a.text.strip()`

Instead:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url='https://shop.eziline.com/product/uncategorized/umrah-management-system/'
r=requests.get(url)
soup=bs(r.content,'lxml')
name=soup.find(class_='product_title entry-title').text.strip()
print(name)
price=soup.select_one('#main-content .woocommerce-Price-amount bdi').text.strip()
print(price)
detail=soup.find(class_='woo-product-details_short-description').text.strip()
print(detail)
category=soup.select_one('.cats-link a').text.strip()
print(category)
```

Answer (score 1):

The attributes you are using in the `find` method apply to more than one tag, you can view all the tags using `findAll` as follows:

```py
for t in soup.findAll('span',class_='woocommerce-Price-amount amount'):
    print(str(t) + "\n")
```

which will result in the following output

```html
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>0.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></bdi></span>

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>0.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></bdi></span>

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">350.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></span>

<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>850.00<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span></bdi></span>
```

> in your code the find method returns the first occurrence of a `span` with classes `woocommerce-Price-amount amount`, and hence the output is 0.00
> [image]

to get only the last tag which is the price you can use

```py
price = soup.findAll('span',class_='woocommerce-Price-amount amount')[-1].text.strip()
```